# Can't delete files when nginx is running

Tags: nginx

On Debian Squeeze, when nginx is running, it puts a handle on my development files (css, html) and I am unable to delete them unless I stop nginx. This is a problem because it's my development environment (I wouldn't care if it was production), is there any setting I can switch so it doesn't put a lock on all my files?

Comment: That doesn't sound like normal Linux behavior. Do you have some command output?

Comment: When I try to delete it, it says "text file is busy". Here's the lsof output:

    `COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    nginx   1534 www-data   12r   REG   0,18    32401    8 style.css`

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to (1) delete the files, and (2) replace them? And what type of filesystem is storing these files?

Comment: Solved this by turning `open_file_cache` off

Got the answer from here
http://serverfault.com/questions/450991/how-to-prevent-nginx-from-locking-files-on-mounted-samba-partition-in-centos-6

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is:

Your files aren't actually on a UNIX or Linux filesystem, but on a Windows-based filesystem, either mounted locally (NTFS) or remotely via SMB/CIFS. These filesystems don't permit one process to remove a file being used by another process.

On a normal UNIX or Linux filesystem, you could replace the file with no issues, and the process that had the file open would still use the old file until it closed it, at which point it would be permanently deleted.

The solution here is to move your files off the NTFS or CIFS share and onto a native filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the guess, but the problem was that I had a setting in nginx that locks files, I turned that off on development environments, and it is working normally now.

Comment: Well, it's not a bug, just the way Windows filesystems work.

Comment: @Ayub Indeed, mentioning that you were serving files from a network filesystem on another OS would have been very helpful.